# User proof network app with distant database

Tags: design, c++, database, security, qt

I’m currently writing a software for my company (3rd world country), and I wanted it as simple as possible to install and maintain, so I started with `Qt` and no server app beside the database, (`MariaDB` or `MySQL`). The app is made to be used by different users on the same machine.

The app the communicating directly with the database, authentication and permissions are handled by the app against the database, only the database settings and a hashed master password to change them are kept locally (using `QSettings`) and set by the IT of the company (currently me) not the user himself. Now I’m wondering how to “user proof” that.

Ultimately, a user can open the settings and directly communicate with the database to change values. Encrypting the values would help but it wouldn’t be “secured” as I would either have to store the encryption key in the settings, or hard code it in the app. Some malicious users will try to break the app, to change the stocks values or to make an invoice disappear (that’s why they are doing with our old system, hidden by frequent malfunctions, so no ultimate proof, that’s why I’m recording something from scratch) but it’s also very unlikely our users have the skills to disassemble and find the KDF algorithm or the hard coded passphrase. I can’t tie the passphrase to a user’s desktop session or login, as multiple users can use the same machine.

The choice was made not to have a web server and APIs to have less component to maintain for the IT, so I’m looking for ideas to secure the app a little bit better without APIs. Any idea ?

Comment: 90% of this work is preventing them from accessing the computer in the first place. Are you saying that these "bad actors" have direct, un-hindered access to the computer running this software and database? If that's the case, you might as well use paper invoices and a physical safe. Your computer is compromised, fix that first.

Comment: So, if i understand it correct, you cant implement a proper security (for example with a frontend, a secured backend and then the database behind that) because of some reasons, therefore you wish to rely on obscuring the authentication mechanism in the hope that the malicious users are not clever enough. Before you follow that decision, calculate the damage IF a user is clever enough (and perhaps tells another user about his findings). Then decide again which path is less expensive in the long run. It not about "being secure", its about "being secure enough for my need".

Comment: Sounds like you made a desastrous architectural decision right from the start. For your kind of scenario, a web app would be way more appropriate. And what you think it is more effort for the IT: deploying a server app to **one** web server, or deploying an app to **several** clients?

Comment: @RonBeyer We currently have a restaurant and our current software works entirely based on network filesystem. To prevent users (and viruses) to directly access the files, we open an empty and readonly share on the client and the software uses another UNC (written in an ini file) to access its files. Since 10 years, it's "still" safe, but they constantly try to make it crash and somehow they discovered a procedure to make an invoice disappear like on an invoice they shut down the computer or disconnect the network cable, and they earn pocket money. Doesn't seem compromised, but a software issue

Comment: @JanRecker Well... I agree I should think about the less expensive and problematic path, no matter how I twist the issue, I'm coming back to having to put a backend in the middle. I'm allowed to sell this solution on my side after that, and many many companies in my country (congo) don't have servers in their companies or simple desktop computers as servers. Therefore, for them to add and maintain a web server won't make them change their software. Also, I can't rely on an internet connection as it's very expensive. I'll think about the backend, thanks

Comment: @DocBrown Unfortunately, for the stock management (with a barcode reader) or the bar and restaurants, a web app would be hard to implement, especially with the ticket printers. Also, trust me, we are skilled to climb walls, put cables in complicated paths, and reboot a computer, but it's been 5 years since I'm teaching my team about CIDR (as used by our routers) for instance, they still only know 255.255.255.0 and put that on 10 computers network. They only know how to maintain a windows computer crashing, let alone a web server... Really skilled network or sysadmins are rare

Comment: @Max13: if there is special hardware which forces you to make it a desktop application, you should mention it in the question. However, I am pretty sure today there are solutions for interfacing a bar code reader or a ticket printer at the client with a web app [for barcodes, see here](https://blog.classycode.com/scanning-barcodes-in-progressive-web-apps-using-angular-5d5a9d50bd8). I understand your admin's know-how problem, of course, but setting up a web-server system isn't rocket science today anymore. The real problem might be the amount of existing code ...

Comment: ... but beware, don't run into the [sunk cost fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunk_cost).

Comment: @DocBrown The scanners we have are HID scanners, behaving like keyboards. We can connect them to mobiles but it would make us buy smartphones. A better solution (with a web app) would be a desktop companion app capturing the "keyboard" exclusively. I'm really thinking about the costs because I'm trading time (add a backend and change how the app communicates) and costs (more time + worst case a new machine) for security now. I'm 99% sure an obfuscated key is the least expansive path, I'm still thinking about the remaining 1%… Thanks for the advices